# Facebook Open Graph Tags og:image does not show given image

Tags: html, facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

There is same Open Graph Tags og:image url for five pages. For some reason the given image is shown only on one page and for the rest four facebook chooses some other image from the page.

Any ideas?

This is the page: http://time-time.net/timer/timers-and-clocks.php
There 'countdown timer' shows wanted image, but the others gets the page logo as og:image.

Facebook debugger shows that everything is okay (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: Can't reproduce. I see the digital tube image when sharing every page. Are you sure there wasn't a browser caching issue perhaps?

Comment: Solved, thanks. Must have been the browser or similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to me.
[image: og:image]

Where does Facebook not show this image?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the "Graph API" right before the `<head>`.

```
<meta prefix="og: https://graph.facebook.com/10151069666995572">
```